# Is Reliability Component a vertex?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, definition, operations-research

The term *component* has a distinct definition in graph theory from *vertex* while the terms *components* and *vertices* can be mostly the same in Realiability Engineering, my intuition. So how is the term *component* Operations Research (OR) such as Reliability Engineering usually defined?

**Is the reliability component a vertex as defined in graph theory?**

Answer (score 1):

Consider

> [image]
> [image]

where the source is the book System Signatures and their Applications in Engineering Reliability. Springer preview is [here](https://www.google.fi/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjY6av13JHNAhWKwBQKHT-XCycQFgghMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780387717968-c2.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-433002-p173734640&usg=AFQjCNEFnfZMJfhiIwnFEuteTyElP6TcAg).
I recited on the thinking in chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/30145842#30145842) where I came to **conclusion that a component (reliability term) is a vertex (graph theoretical term).**

**Puzzles**

> I. set of all the systems's components equal {1,2,3,4,5}? Or is this wrong?
>
> II. algebraic union of all minimal path sets is?
>
> III. what does "minimal path sets consist of the collection $\{\{1,4\},\{1,3,5\},\{2,5\},\{2,3,4\}\}$ mean?

**Answers**

> III. minimal path sets = {{1,4},{1,3,5},{2,5},{2,3,4}}
>
> II. Algebraic union of all minimal path sets is U_i S_i= {1,4}\cup {1,3,5}\cup {2,5} \cup {2,3,4}={1,2,3,4,5}
>
> I. set of system's components equal to {1,2,3,4,5}

---

**Example 1.**

Notice that the bridge system in Fig.2.2. **does have** the component $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ by the property (ii) even though not minimal.

Answer (score 0):

In reliability theory one considers the system to be modelled as composed of a number of separate "components".  Thus the components are the smallest parts of the system that the modeller chooses to consider.

Comment: So the components are modeled as vertices but they can represent something different inside? Is it too arrogant approach to assume the components to be vertices? I cannot think of a case where the components are not vertices, can you?

Comment: AFAIK, in a graphical representation the components would normally be represented as vertices.